# How to run Flutter app on physical Iphone without xcode connection

Tags: ios, flutter

In order to test my flutter application, I installed it on my Iphone from Xcode and everything went well. Now, when I close Xcode or when my Iphone is not connected to my computer (by cable or network) I can't open the application.

I was wondering if there was a possibility to install a flutter application on Iphone and make the application work without Xcode.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Create .ipa file of Your application through Xcode*

upload yours.IPA file on the following website after the successfully uploading the Website give you an Linke. open the link in your iPhone it will automatically install in your iPhone

http://diawi.com

Answer (score 4):

Run the release version using: flutter run --release